# Github pages URL keeps redirecting to old, deleted custom domain

Tags: github, dns

i host my jekyll blog on github and used to use a custom apex domain for it and that worked just fine.

Yesterday i wanted to discontinue the domain and go back to the standard .github.io adress, so i deleted the DNS Entrys on Namecheap and the custom domain entry in the github repo settings under "Pages" (also made sure the CNAME file is gone, i even deleted the whole repo and set it up from scratch) but still the .github.io Adress redirects to my old custom domain and shows a 404.

Is there a way to solve this?

I can think of trying to assign a new custom domain, but i dont have one right now and just want to use the standard domain for now.

Comment: Ok nvm, deleting browser data resolved the redirection.

But now i get straight to a 404.html from github, so theres another thing going wrong.